# Recursion - list of strings and lists

Tags: python, string, list, recursion

Is it possible to transform list of strings and lists into usual (normal) list using **recursion** (it's just an example. the list could be even deeper and more complex)

I'm not that good at recursion yet, any help or tips would be appreciated!

Comment: yes, it is possible, is that the only question?

Comment: Certainly possible to a degree. A note on the "deeper and more complex" part: there is a maximum recursive depth in Python.

Comment: That's exactly what function `collapse` from module `more_itertools` does. The recursion [in its source-code](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#collapse) basically follows the same logic as Samwise's answer below, although with iterables instead of lists, and some extra flexibility such as specifying a base type other than string, or the maximum depth.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea with recursion is to break the problem down into smaller pieces -- figure out how to solve the simplest case, and then express the more complex cases in ways that shrink them down toward the simplest case.

```
>>> def flatten(nested):
...     flat = []
...     for i in nested:
...         if isinstance(i, list):
...             flat.extend(flatten(i))
...         else:
...             flat.append(i)
...     return flat
... 
>>> flatten(['hello', ['hey', 'heey', ['hey']], 'hi', ['hihi']])
['hello', 'hey', 'heey', 'hey', 'hi', 'hihi']
```

Each call to `flatten` takes a list of lists/strings, and is expected to return a list of only strings.  It does this by going over all of its elements, and `flatten`ing the lists.